# How do I change the port and SSL port number in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017, iis-express

I was working on a project and everything was working perfectly in IIS.  Unfortunately, our IT guy had us change our github account to a different corporate account(it's a long story...)  Anyways, after this change, I can not get my local application to run correctly.  Due to some settings I need to use the exact port numbers I was using before I had to switch accounts.

My original project was saved as: C:/projects/CustomerWebApp1

It is now being stored as: C:/projects/CustomerWebApp2

I went to the applicationhost.config of CustomerWebApp1 and copied the settings into settings of the CustomerWebApp2.

Unfortunately, when I start up Visual Studio, the settings are getting overwritten.  How do I modify VS to use the port number I'd prefer to use?

Comment: Right-click on project > Select Web Tab > Update the Project Url

Comment: You have to keep several files in sync, or VS decides to do that for you, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/vs-diagnostics.html#background

Comment: @AnkushJain Thanks a million!  That was the correct answer!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to modify the `<SSLPort>443XX</SSLPort>` in your csproj ? That solve everything for me in this case.

The IIS Express SSL port can be from 44300 to 44399.

Tell me if that worked for you